# What is the Linux equivalent of DOS "dir /s /b filename"?

Tags: ls

List all files/dirs in or below the current directory that match 'filename'.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The direct equivalent is

```
find . -iname <filename>
```

which will list all files and directories called `<filename>` in the current directory and any subdirectories, ignoring case.

If your version of find doesn't support `-iname`, you can use `-name` instead.  Note that unlike `-iname`, `-name` is case sensitive.

If you only want to list files called `<filename>`, and not directories, add `-type f`

```
find . -iname <filename> -type f
```

If you want to use wildcards, you need to put quotes around it, e.g.

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -type f
```

otherwise the shell will expand it.

As others have pointed out, you can also do:

```
find . | grep "\.txt$"
```

`grep` will print lines based on regular expressions, which are more powerful than wildcards, but have a different syntax.

See `man find` and `man grep` for more details.

Comment: If `<filename>` contains wildcards, use quotes around it, e.g. `find . -name '*.txt'`.

Comment: @Gilles, updated my answer to say that, thanks.

Comment: And if you don't want a <filename>, just `find .` will do.

Comment: Using `<filename>` as marker for userinput is a bad habit in command-line environment, where `< and >` most of the time have specific meaning. I suggest just using `filename`, maybe FILENAME to emphasize it. Most people will understand, and those, who won't, might cause harm when not understanding that they aren't supposed to hit less-than or greater-than sign.

Comment: `<filename>` is a convention in a lot of UNIX documentation, so I think it's useful for people to be aware of it, but I agree `FILENAME` might be easier to understand.

Comment: `find -iname <filename>` is better since it is case-insensitive like DOS

Answer (score 8):

Some shells allow `ls **/filename`, which is quite convenient.

Comment: Good point.  In recent versions of bash, running `shopt -s globstar; echo **/filename` is equivalent to `find . -name "filename"`.  It also works in zsh.

Comment: This 'ls **/filename` is fine, but seems not go more that one directory level deep.

Comment: @sopalajo-de-arrierez If you do `shopt -s globstar`, it will probably work for you. Recursive globbing is a feature that is available only in some shells, and sometimes, it is not on by default.

Comment: Ops... I understand now, @ShawnJ.Goff: the `shopt` command enables the option `globstar on`. Now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with

```
find . | egrep filename
```

Comment: You could also do it in one with `find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*filename.*'` (I don't know if the `egrep` part is important, but you used `egrep` in your answer so I included it)

Comment: You can, but grep is different than the equivalent DOS command.  `grep` uses regular expressions, while the DOS command uses shell wildcards.

Comment: Come to think of it, shell globs are also different than DOS wildcards.  For instance, `find . -name "*.*"` won't do what you'd expect from a DOS background.  Globs are close enough to be recognizable, though, while regexes are an entirely new beast.

Comment: What does `*.*.*` do in a modern dos i.e. windows cmd? What about `*.*.*.*`?

Answer (score 0):

It can be also: `tree -if </your/path>` or `'pwd'` as a path