# Detecting pattern at the end of a line with grep

Tags: grep

If I do:

```
$ ls -R
.:
4Shared/  Cloud/

./4Shared:
UFAIZLV2R7.part3.rar

./Cloud:
UFAIZLV2R7.part2.rar.part
UFAIZLV2R7.part1.rar.part
UFAIZLV2R7.part4.rar.part
```

If I want to list the `.rar` files only, and I use **grep**, it will show me too the `.rar.part` files, what is not my wish.
I am solving this using `find` or `ls **/*.rar` as told in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7169/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-of-dos-dir-s-b-filename) and they work fine, but I would like to learn if it is possible to do it via `grep`.

I have tried (thinking about `EOL`):

```
ls -R | grep ".rar\n"
```

with no results.
I think that the problem lies in discover if the greping is found **at the end of the line**, but I am not sure.

Any help out here, please?

Comment: Why would you want to use `grep` in this case?  Why not `find`?

Comment: @devnull, knowing how to detect patterns that are only at the end of a line could be useful in many cases. For example: portability, usage in routers with embedded too-simplistic Linux, usage with UnxUtils for Windows (its `find` command conflicts with the Windows one) and... learning ;-) . The question is not about "Listing Files in a dir" (that is just a custom example) but rather "Understanding the grep command usage"

Comment: honestly, if you're counting on the end of a line to be your separator, then you should be using `ls -1R`.

Comment: And you don't even need `grep`. See my answer.

Comment: @mikeserv, what could happen without the `-1R` switch. Apparently the results are the same.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Yeah - needs -q not -1.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The `$` anchor matches the end of a line.

```
ls -R | grep '\.rar$'
```

You can also use `find` for this:

```
find . -name '*.rar'
```

Comment: I didn't realize the "." needs to be escaped in grep. Is it treated as a wild card?

Comment: @thebunnyrules "." in regex means one of any character.

Comment: This does not work for me on macOS with zsh.  Soon as I add the $ I get no matches, when I can see without the $ that I should get a match.  ^ works for beginning of the line, but $ doesn't work for EOL

Comment: @swpalmer Only thing I can think is you might need `ls -lR` on mac, assuming `-R` doesn't imply `-l` like it does in linux. The `find` version is POSIX and should work everywhere.

Comment: @jordanm Sorry, the issue is with grep not ls.  I'm doing "cat list_of_words.txt | grep '^lunar$'"  Without the $ I get a list of 5 words: lunar, lunaria, lunarian, lunarians, lunars  .. if I add the $ then I expected to get just "lunar" but I get nothing. Using \b instead of $ works.

Comment: @swpalmer that means your line doesn't end in a "r", it ends in a blank space after the "r"

Comment: @jordanm Sort of, I confirmed the problem by dumping the hex bytes with 'od -tx1a'.  The line separators in that file are /r/n not /n

Answer (score 14):

In addition to your question please note that `.rar` does not only match ".rar" but matches every single character (including `.`) before the `rar`. In this case probably not a problem but `.` must be escaped in regexes.

```
ls -R | grep "\.rar$"
```

Comment: Did you mean that `.asc` is like `*asc` pattern? So it will match, for example, `whereverasc`.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez No, it does not match every group of characters but every single character, e.g. `xrar`.

Answer (score 7):

You can also instruct `grep` to look for your string starting at a word boundary. There is such a boundary between `.` (a *non-word* character) and `r` (a *word* character). Depending on your `grep` implementation, the word boundary operator can be `\b` or possibly `\<` or `[[:<:]]` (boundary left of a word only), `\>` or `[[:>:]]` (right).

```
$ ls -R | grep '\brar$'
```

#### Example

Say I have this sample data.

```
$ ls -1
afile.rar
xrar
UFAIZLV2R7.part1.rar.part
UFAIZLV2R7.part2.rar.part
```

This command would find only the file with the `.rar` extension.

```
$ ls -R | grep '\brar$'
afile.rar
```

#### How this works?

> The metacharacter `\b` is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length.

#### Situations where this won't work

If you have files that are named `blah-rar` these will get detected as well.

```
$ ls -R | grep '\brar$'
afile-rar
afile.rar
```

That's because characters other than a alphanumerics are typically considered boundary characters, and so would slip past this approach.

Comment: Seems to be the same at first sight, but it is slightly different, indeed. Thanks, @slm. Does it bother if I use double quotes `"` instead of simple quotes?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez - nope works either way. This will find any files that may be named starting w/ `.rar`. But these won't be an issue with the use of `ls -R`. Only if you happened to use `ls -Ra`.

Comment: Would one of you be interested in explaining this slight difference to the public?

Comment: @HaukeLaging The `-P` switch to `grep` in my example. That triggers PCRE interpretation of the argument.

Comment: @slm That's obvious but why is that useful? `echo xrar | grep -P '.rar$'`

Comment: @HaukeLaging - ah crap. I though I added an example in my test cases that covered that scenario but now I see I've missed that. Thanks! I'll delete, this will do nothing additional to the regular `grep`. I thought it was doing literal dots by default.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - here's I've recast this A using `\b` instead of PCRE. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: slm, if you're using `grep` you need to keep using `-1R` to handle file/dir names containing `\n` - but if you look at mine...

Comment: You're point about `ls -1R` is valid. The regex you used in your example didn't quite work though. Might be able to refactor it?

Comment: @slm, there is no `-P` switch right now on your text. Maybe you have accidentally deleted it on last edit?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez - further testing showed that wouldn't have worked so I've recast this answer in a different direction now.

Comment: Yeah, a bit messy. But the `\b` info is very useful, anyway. Thanks, @slm. The '-1' thing is what I still haven't understood. Why should it be needed? My tests show the same result without it.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez - if a file contains a newline character (`\n`) which is a legal character. The `ls -1R` will force the files to be displayed in a single column regardless.

Answer (score 4):

Use single quotes to make the $ work as end-of-line. If you want to grep with some variable also, use combination of double and single quotes as below:

```
grep "$var"'$'
```

*My previous post was deleted saying it is duplicate. Let me explain how this is different.*

The other posts mention either full use of double quotes `""`, or full use of single quotes `''`. They both have their own limitations. Following explains it.

The problem with all double quotes is following:
`grep "pattern$"` gives following error: `Illegal variable name.`

And using all single quotes works, but if you want variable substitution, all single quotes will **not** work. For example:

If I have string `A_BOOK`, including other strings in a file FILE.

```
$ cat FILE
A_BOOK
B_BOOK_NOT_LAST
C_BOOK
```

If I set the BOOK to a variable BK

```
set BK = BOOK
```

If I grep with all double quotes, I get the following error: `grep "${BK}$" FILE*`: 1st $ for variable substitution, 2nd for end of pattern 
(*Illegal variable name*).

If I grep with all single quotes, the variable substitution does not happen. 
`grep '${BK}$' FILE` returns nothing

If I use a combination of double and single quotes, I get what I expect. Double quotes for variable substitution, and single quotes for end of pattern.

```
$ grep "${BK}"'$'  # << gives expected output
A_BOOK
C_BOOK
```

Comment: Looks like you're using csh. The `"foo$"` syntax works fine on sh and family.

Comment: Yes Olorin. I am using tcsh. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

```
ls -1R -I"?" -I"??" -I"???" -I"*[!.][!r][!a][!r]"
```

You don't need `grep` at all.

***NOTE:*** The above works... except it still gets *at least* `afile-rar` and I don't understand why. I'll leave it here, but I'm not proud of it. In any case, as others have said:

```
find . '*.rar'
```

Comment: This didn't block files named `xrar` or `afile-rar`.

Comment: I'm still getting the other files in the output.

Comment: @slm What other files? I think it might be cause they're too short. I just noticed that myself. I fixed that too.

Comment: The files `afile-rar` and `xrar` are still being included in the output. No change with your latest mods either. Pesky problem no? It's fun trying to solve it without the regular methods 8-)

Comment: @slm Yeah, it's why I come here. I don't understand why the `-dash` gets through. The `xrar` thing I could handle, but not the `-dash.` I don't understand the `-dash.`

Answer (score 0):

If after following the above and nothing works, it could be due to line-endings. To fix, do: `dos2unix pr0n.txt` and do your `grep` again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and something came to mind suddenly.  Terminal color codes...  At some stage I actually aliased `ls` to `ls --color=always` and that meant that line start and line end may be terminal color escape sequences instead of the content that's visible on the screen.

I have since changed my alias back to `ls --color=auto`, so `ls | grep "^ABC"` now works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Use pattern followed by `$` in double quotes.

Example: I want to find the line that ends with semicolon in a file `hey.txt`

```
grep ";$" hey.txt
```

Output : prints the lines that end with semicolon.

Comment: The issue is finding _filenames_ that end in a particular string, not lines in a file.