# How can I grep for '^M$'?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, special-characters

I'm trying to extract lines from a subtitle (.srt) file. When I grep for a specific line number, I get the answer I expect:

```
% grep -e "^817" ponyo.srt                                             
817
%
```

but when I try to grep for that line including a carriage return (or a carriage return and EOL), I get a blank line:

```
% grep -e "^817\r" ponyo.srt 

% grep -e "^817^M$" ponyo.srt

%
```

Here's the text file using "cat -e" to show hidden characters:

```
% cat -e ponyo.srt 
1^M$
00:04:38,478 --> 00:04:43,381^M$
The Beginning^M$
^M$
2^M$
00:04:44,751 --> 00:04:51,122^M$
PONYO ON THE CLIFF BY THE SEA^M$
^M$
474^M$
01:00:23,016 --> 01:00:25,041^M$
Stay here with Ponyo.^M$
^M$
475^M$
01:00:25,285 --> 01:00:28,618^M$
I'm going too.^M$
Let's take Ponyo with us.^M$
^M$
817^M$
01:40:08,532 --> 01:40:13,834^M$
<i>Oh he 's my favorite little boy</i>^M$
^M$
823^M$
01:40:32,456 --> 01:40:38,156^M$
Studio Ghibli^M$
^M$
824^M$
01:40:39,530 --> 01:40:42,624^M$
The End^M$
^M$
825^M$
01:40:42,766 --> 01:40:45,792^M$
English translation by^M$
Jim Hubbert and Rieko Izutsu-Vajirasarn^M$
English subtitles by^M$
Aura^M$
^M$
%
```

How can I grep for the end of lines and get the whole line in the results?

**EDIT:** To add, just searching for EOL returns nothing, as I would expect:

```
% grep -e "^817$" ponyo.srt 
%
```

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=grep+regex&ia=web

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124462/detecting-pattern-at-the-end-of-a-line-with-grep#124463

Comment: @jsotola Neither of those links appear to address my concern. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It seems like you probably just want to install dos2unix and run `mac2unix` on the file before attempting to work with it.

Comment: Do you have `grep` aliased to something that includes a `--color=` specification?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes. "alias grep='grep --color=auto'" I'll remove that and try again.

Comment: ... see for example [grep --color=auto breaks when ^M is inside colored match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350352/grep-color-auto-breaks-when-m-is-inside-colored-match)

Comment: @steeldriver Yep, that was the problem. Do you want to answer and get credit? (Or I can answer myself and hog all the fake internet points for myself.)

Comment: @JohnnyRollerfeet ... first link was to use regex to match a whole line ... second link indicates that `$` matches to end of line, no need for trying to match `\r` or `\n`

Comment: @jsotola Using just $ doesn't return a result because there is a character (^M) between the number and the EOL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grep --color=auto breaks when ^M is inside colored match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350352/grep-color-auto-breaks-when-m-is-inside-colored-match)

Comment: The native EOL (end-of-line) character in UNIX is LF `\n`, not CR `\r`, so matching `$` may not be what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

(Credit to @steeldriver for the answer.)

As mentioned in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350352/grep-color-auto-breaks-when-m-is-inside-colored-match) `grep --color` changes the way grep writes responses to the terminal in a way that interferes with writing `^M` to the screen. I was using `alias grep='grep --color=auto'` in my bash settings. To bypass the alias, both to troubleshoot this issue and to create a permanent solution, I used `\` to have the shell use grep without the alias.

```
% \grep -e "^817^M" ponyo.srt
817
%
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things appear to be causing a hangup - first, you're using double quotes, which means the shell will interpret some things rather than passing them all verbatim. Secondly, you may need to escape that dollar sign with a \ since even with single quotes, my shell won't properly search for one. With those parameters changed, `grep` will in fact return the lines you're looking for (or at least it seems that way to me).

Comment: See the comment above by @Steeldriver.