# grep searching end of line pattern from DOS files

Tags: grep, regular-expression, newlines

- Like [Detecting pattern at the end of a line with grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124462/detecting-pattern-at-the-end-of-a-line-with-grep), but for DOS files of CRLF line terminators.
- Like in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462633/374303, one way is to use `dos2unix` but I don't have it in my remote server.

I.e., `\r` is not working for `grep` in Extended Regular Expression mode?:

```
$ printf 'abcd\r\n' | grep -Ec 'd\r$'
0

$ printf 'abcd\r\n' | grep -c 'd.$'
1

$ printf 'abcd\r\n' | grep -Pc 'd\r$'
1
```

I thought `\r` is part of Extended Regular Expressions, like in
https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/boost/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html. No?
Or it is indeed a limitation of `grep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `\r` is not part of standard [basic](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) nor [extended](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) regular expressions except [in `awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04), though some `grep`s support it as an extension like the `grep` from ast-open which supports it in all its regexp flavours (with `-E`, `-X`, `-P` and with the default BRE).

It's part of `perl` regular expressions though, as well as PCRE ones, so should be supported by `grep` implementations that support a `-P` for those.

Most shells these days support the `$'...'` form of quotes from ksh93, where `\r` is expanded to a carriage return. So with those, you can do:

```
grep $'d\r$'
```

PCRE allows specifying the type of line delimiter with directives such as `(*LF)`, `(*CRLF)`, `(*CR)`, but that can't be used in `grep -P` even in those where perl-like matching is implemented using PCRE, because `grep` works on the *contents* of one (LF-delimited) line at a time, so the LF is not found in the string that the regexp matches against.

It could be used however in `pcregrep`'s `M`ultiline mode:

```
$ printf '%s\r\n' foo abcd bar | pcregrep -M '(*CRLF)d$' | sed -n l
abcd\r$
```

(`sed -n l` to reveal the the CR as `\r`).

With GNU `grep`, you could use it with the `-z` flag that makes it work on NUL-delimited records instead of lines:

```
$ printf '%s\r\n' foo abcd bar | grep -oPz '(*CRLF)(?m).*d$' | tr '\0' '\n' | sed -n l
abcd$
```

(also enabling the `m`ultiline flag for `$` to match at the end of each line in addition to at the end of the record, and `tr`ansliterating the NULs to LF on output for display).