# What is the Unix (QNX) equivalent of Windows command line "dir /s /b"

Tags: ls, qnx

The question [What is the Linux equivalent of DOS “dir /s /b filename”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7169/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-of-dos-dir-s-b-filename) comes close but it winds up playing a file find operation for all such named file names.

I'm however looking to do a directory contents diff comparison with a directory on a Windows machine and compare it to what should be a similarly constructed directory on a **QNX** box. I want to run the directory enumerating command on both machines, do some text file manipulation to convert path delimiting characters and root drives and what not to get them into a compatible format for an insightful diff.

I can generate a folder manifest of all subdirectories and files therein with `dir /b /s`, and get output formatted as a bunch of paths...

```
c:\Temp>dir /b /s
c:\Temp\Subfolder1
C:\Temp\Subfolder1\File1.txt
C:\Temp\Subfolder1\File2.txt
...
```

I can see `dir /s` becomes `ls -R`, but how do I get the `/B` equivalent of the path output formatting?

Comment: The answer is the same as in the other question, except you leave out the `-name` option, so it doesn't filter by name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`find` may give you all that you need. It has a little more overhead as it performs more tests than `ls` alone, but if you want the path information in the output then this may be the simplest way to achieve that.

If you're going to compare two systems, then you should probably do some text editing first and swap `\` with `/`, and remove the `C:` prefix. Then sort the lists and use `diff` to spot the changes. `sed` will be your friend here. Follow-up with a comment if you want this too.

Answer (score 18):

There isn't a flag for `ls` which will do what you ask, but you can accomplish it with several other tools, the easiest being (possibly) `find`:

```
find .
```

Comment: or simply `find`  The default expression is `.`

Comment: True. Anyway I think it is a good practice to include defaults in Q/A posts, as they might not be obvious to everyone.

Comment: @user4556274 It may be for GNU `find`, but other implementations follow the POSIX standard and requires a directory operand.

Answer (score 5):

tree -if

-i to not indent
-f to print path

Comment: Interesting, show some console output to your answer; I can't find that command from my QNX box `-bash: tree: command not found`

Comment: I'm on my phone so can't test it, but it's in the man page at https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree

Comment: It's from http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/, and packaged as `tree` in a number of Linux distributions.

Comment: `tree` is my tool of choice to inspect directory structure, but it is not installed by default on most systems.

Answer (score 5):

In order to get the actual path prefixed (assuming that's important), do

```
find "$(pwd)"
```

Comment: If you are using a bash-like shell, no need to invoke an external command; `find "${PWD}"` should be enough. Not sure if that works on QNX, though.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Well if you want the symlink path rather than the real path ...

Comment: True, it might depend on the exact semantics of each. Don't forget that at least GNU bash has a built-in `pwd` as well as the external /bin/pwd, too, which also differ in how they handle directories reached by symlinks.